# How Do I Avoid Access Denied When Reclaiming Local Libraries in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, folder-redirection, windows-10-v1511

After installing Windows 10 from scratch (now updated to the latest 1151 update), my local directories (ie. Documents and Pictures) are mirroring whatever is placed in my OneDrive Documents and Pictures folders (Oddly enough Videos, Music, and Downloads are not affected). Windows 10 lists these folders as my local "Documents" and "Pictures." However, the location is re-directed to my OneDrive. When attempting to reclaim and redirect the local folders to the default "C:\Users" locations I am denied access. Anyone know why these folders got messed up in the first place and why I can't have access to some of my local libraries? I can manually navigate to the respective local directories but am unsure as to why they would have been replaced by OneDrive in the main navigation areas. Please see images for more information. Know that I am the only user of this computer and have full administrative access.

[image: Side-Pane View, notice the syncing notifications]

[image: Attempting to re-locate directory]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to direct `OneDrive/Pictures` to a User profile directory "Pictures"?  They really should be separate for alot of reasons.

Comment: I'm not attempting to redirect OneDrive/Pictures to the User profile. To clarify that is what happened and I'm trying to figure out why they are not separated. Somehow Windows 10 mixed the folders. In the main navigation pane "Local Documents and Pictures" are not separated from the "OneDrive Documents and Pictures."

Comment: Is your local account still connected to a `Microsoft Account`?

Comment: The account I am using is a Microsoft Account. The first account I used to log in to the system was a Microsoft rather than a local account.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between those two statements.  If you are logging into your Microsoft Account that implies your local account is attached to a Microsoft Account..  What do you use to restore the image of your system?

Comment: I re-installed Windows 10 from scratch (blank slate). Next I logged into Windows 10 using previously created Microsoft Account credentials (not an isolated local account). The distinction is to clarify that this is not an account locally produced on the system- meaning it may carry over setting or permissions that are attached to a Microsoft/cloud based account. Does that make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlink my Documents folder from my OneDrive account?](https://superuser.com/questions/1205668/how-to-unlink-my-documents-folder-from-my-onedrive-account)

Answer (score 3):

According to a [Microsoft Support article](http://Operation%20to%20change%20a%20personal%20folder%20location%20fails%20in%20Windows) found by [vembutech](https://superuser.com/questions/1205668/how-to-unlink-my-documents-folder-from-my-onedrive-account#comment1756728_1205668), you can use the following workaround.

---

> **Important**
>
> Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems might
>   occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it,
>   [back up the registry for restoration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows) in case problems occur.
>
> To work around this issue, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Right-click the Windows logo at the lower-left corner of the screen, and then click **Run**.
> 2. Type regedit.exe and press Enter. If **User Account Control** window pops up, click **Yes**.
> 3. In Registry Editor, browse to the following path: **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
>      Shell Folders`**
> 4. Refer to the following table to find the registry key for the folder that encounters this issue, and change it to the default value.
>
> ```
> +-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+
> |  Folder   |              Registry key              |      Default value      |
> +-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+
> | Downloads | {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B} | %USERPROFILE%\Downloads |
> | Desktop   | Desktop                                | %USERPROFILE%\Desktop   |
> | Favorites | Favorites                              | %USERPROFILE%\Favorites |
> | Music     | My Music                               | %USERPROFILE%\Music     |
> | Pictures  | My Pictures                            | %USERPROFILE%\Pictures  |
> | Videos    | My Video                               | %USERPROFILE%\Videos    |
> | Documents | Personal                               | %USERPROFILE%\Documents |
> +-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+
> ```
>
> 5. Restart the Explorer.exe process to make the changes take effect. To do this, you can use either of the following steps:
>
>    - Restart the process in Task Manager.
>    - Sign out, and then sign in.
>    - Restart the computer.

<sup>*</sup>Answer reposted from a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1205668/how-to-unlink-my-documents-folder-from-my-onedrive-account).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 fix: Here's my solution for redirecting your local files back to the PC and not the Onedrive folder. After playing around for the past couple days, I found this:

1. Go into the *System* tab after pressing the Windows Key -> *Settings*. You should see the System tab on the top left of the Settings window.
2. Click it, after that, look for the *Storage* tab (It should be the 8th tab from the top). Click it.
3. Next you should see the redirect files page. Change all the OneDrive files to (your PC name) and hit *Apply*.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. However, all of the save locations mentioned in the Settings area are already re-directed to "This PC (C:)." OneDrive is not mentioned anywhere on the page despite the fact that the "This PC" locations are replicating my OneDrive (as previously mentioned in original post). See original post for updated images showing the area you mentioned.